# Create a simple html ranking table which uses data and updates from external excel file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, datatables

I need to create a very simple table which will consist of three columns ( Position, Name, Points ) for each row.

This data should be fed from an external file, ideally an Excel document but we can change that if needs be. This external file should contain the name and their associated points. The ranking would be calculated from this and implemented into the table.

The table will be updated  manually every day, but the data should then be reflected in the html table.

Would I be best off using javascript for this?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you started creating it? Show us some code snippets!

Comment: No, I wanted to know the best tool for the job before starting. Apologies if thats not an acceptable question

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not a legit SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create your table with it calculations in Excel and then "Save As" the result in HTML ? Then you just need to paste the result HTML table in your website.

If you want to have dynamic tool online instead of a static HTML table, you can still create it as a spreadsheet tool and converts it as an web-application with [Appizy](http://appizy.com).

Good luck with your project. Nicolas